# sharing data structure with different headers

Tags: c, struct, header, linked-list, header-files

I am writing a program in C and I need it to be built out of different modules.

I defined a data structure in order to create a linked list in one of the modules' header's files.

When I include this header file in other modules my program does not compile.

My struct definition is:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char bla[10];
    int num;
    struct node* next;
}Name;
```

I wonder what is the proper way to implement this.
Thanks

Comment: What error does the compiler give?

Answer (score 1):

In other headers, simply use forward declarations. You don't need to define it, as that will create a duplicate definition. The linker will handle linking in the actual definitions.

So, if you had the given structure defined in header A, to use it in header B, you would just put the following line at the top of the header

```
  struct node;
  typedef struct node Name;
```

Which will then allow you to use the Declaration in function declarations in that header.

If you're trying to actually put function definitions in your header files, you need to use Pre-Processor macros to prevent the file from being recursively included.

in `a.h`, you would put

```
  #ifndef __A
  #define __A
  #include "b.h"
     ...

  #endif
```

And then in `b.h` you would put

```
 #ifndef __B
 #define __B

     ...

 #endif
```

Then, even if you include both `a.h` and `b.h` in `main.c`, there won't be a recursive include, and the compile will succeed.

Ideally, headers are limited to structure/type definitions and function declarations, so forward declaration are all that is needed.